# onblur function doesn't work in google chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am working on mvc application. During development I got a very strange issue, I have three text box and on each one, I need to call onblur event.
when I execute the code, event is called for first text box only, not for second and for third text box again event is called . Here is my code

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#a1,#a2,#a3").blur(function(){
        alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
        });  
     });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    Enter your name: <input type="text" class="c1" id="a3">
    <br><input type="text" class="c1" id="a1">
    <br><input type="text" class="c1" id="a2">
    <p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field to lose focus (blur).</p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work? 
https://jsfiddle.net/ope79u3k/

Comment: dont debug with alert, use `console.log($(this).attr('id'))` your see it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think that there may be some blocking of the alert happening in your browser/sandbox, but the `onblur` works fine (try just console logging what you are currently showing the alert for).